# How to create an iOS project with a XIB in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm running xcode 5.0.1. In previous version Xcode, there was to be a checkbox for not using storyboard when creating a ios project. How do I turn off storyboards and just use xib files in xcode 5.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the built-in project templates in Xcode 5 mandate storyboards, unless you pick the Empty Application template. Your choices therefore boil down to:

- Start every project as an Empty Application and add your view controllers from the ground up
- Start using one of the storyboard-based templates, then:

  - Delete the storyboard file
  - Change the main storyboard setting in your project to be empty
  - Add .xibs to the existing view controllers as needed
  - Implement your app delegate methods as needed to set up a view controller hierarchy

Comment: I prefer #1 because personally. Its a little bit easier adding the code necessary to use .xib's then changing the code in #2 to get rid of the storyboard code.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new project as an empty project. The selection is in the bottom row, second from the right. Then you can add your view controllers in your app delegate. Hope this helps.